Using curl and grep to extract data from a file
i have been trying for hours but with no luck, I want to extract the (id, remote_ip, listen_addr) and put it in a txt file
I have managed to do so with
curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/gGt524CS | grep -e "id" -e "remote_ip" -e "listen_addr" | cut -d\" -f4 > text.txt

but the result I'm getting is not aligned as it should
I want it to be like that in 10 lines:
id@remote_ip:listen_addr 

The result I'm getting looks like this:
9ed1e069802812f484faa68a2c6dd61f6bc1be0b
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
88.99.61.173
8f1f37f30546275dea1f1e2a9e3828e8565f118d
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
212.192.222.35
aac5871efa351872789eef15c2da7a55a68abdad
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
88.218.226.79
2e8c8d2d7f84b602069fc608a151c19840642d07
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
95.216.39.183
d4c5dcfbec11d80399bcf18d83a157259ca3efc7
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
138.201.200.100
d82c661cfec95670271b2e55037e003ff8285741
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
193.124.50.74
2ecf2dd998aa6fbfef370a027510d0f56026cbc3
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
152.53.35.92
e4dcdc1218f8703a16f6cc8d7024af2457661198
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
198.7.125.195
f1ec81f4963e78d06cf54f103cb6ca75e19ea831
tcp://0.0.0.0:26656
217.76.159.104
d6416eb44f9136fc3b03535ae588f63762a67f8e
tcp://0.0.0.0:31656
211.219.19.141

Should be like this:
9ed1e069802812f484faa68a2c6dd61f6bc1be0b@88.99.61.173:26656

Thank you all

I suggest to use a tool which understands JSON, e.g. jq.

Why would you expect grep to merge results into the same line of output? How is it supposed to know which lines should be combined? awk or jq would be better tools for this.

You should provide an example of the input

@Bramar im very new to linux, i will have to check awk or jq thank you for the suggestion

I will try it out thank you @cyrus

With jq:
curl ... | jq -r '.result.peers[] | "\(.node_info.id)@\(.remote_ip):\(.node_info.listen_addr | sub("tcp://0.0.0.0:";""))"'

Output:

9ed1e069802812f484faa68a2c6dd61f6bc1be0b@88.99.61.173:26656
8f1f37f30546275dea1f1e2a9e3828e8565f118d@212.192.222.35:26656
aac5871efa351872789eef15c2da7a55a68abdad@88.218.226.79:26656
2e8c8d2d7f84b602069fc608a151c19840642d07@95.216.39.183:26656
d4c5dcfbec11d80399bcf18d83a157259ca3efc7@138.201.200.100:26656
d82c661cfec95670271b2e55037e003ff8285741@193.124.50.74:26656
2ecf2dd998aa6fbfef370a027510d0f56026cbc3@152.53.35.92:26656
e4dcdc1218f8703a16f6cc8d7024af2457661198@198.7.125.195:26656
f1ec81f4963e78d06cf54f103cb6ca75e19ea831@217.76.159.104:26656
d6416eb44f9136fc3b03535ae588f63762a67f8e@211.219.19.141:31656

Resources used:

Looping thru multiple regex matches with bash
Removing first digits from each line in bash (1-2 char length)


You'd be much better off using a tool that actually understands JSON, like xidel:
$ xidel -s --input-format=json "https://pastebin.com/raw/gGt524CS" -e '
  $json/result/(peers)()/concat(
    node_info/id,"@",remote_ip,
    substring-after(node_info/listen_addr,"tcp://0.0.0.0")
  )
'

The pastebin-url returns JSON as text.
$ xidel -s "https://pastebin.com/raw/gGt524CS" -e '$headers'
[...]
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

For actual JSON that should've been Content-Type: application/json. You can work around that by simply parsing the source with -e 'parse-json($raw)/...', or by forcing the input-format as shown above.
